# Custom Inflections not working on rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

I'm using Rails (3.0.1) and have the following code in initializers/inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
inflect.irregular('nursery', 'nurseries')
end
```

From the console I'm getting:

```
"nursery".pluralize => "nurseries"
"nurseries".singularize => "nurseries"
```

I should be getting:

```
"nurseries".singularize => "nursery"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in 3.0.0, interesting.