# Rails 3 route has incorrect singular form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, activeresource

I have the following routes:

```
resources :businesses, only: [:show, :index, :new, :create] do
  resources :pledge_drives
end
```

This creates the following:

```
% rake routes | grep pledge
     business_pledge_drives GET    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives(.:format)                                         pledge_drives#index
                            POST   /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives(.:format)                                         pledge_drives#create
  new_business_pledge_drife GET    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/new(.:format)                                     pledge_drives#new
 edit_business_pledge_drife GET    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/:id/edit(.:format)                                pledge_drives#edit
      business_pledge_drife GET    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/:id(.:format)                                     pledge_drives#show
                            PUT    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/:id(.:format)                                     pledge_drives#update
                            DELETE /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/:id(.:format)                                     pledge_drives#destroy
```

I do *not* want the URL helper method to be called `business_pledge_drife_path`. How can I correct Rails in its singularization of `drives`? The actual URLs are fine.

**Edit:** [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16244929/38743) got it right. I added the following to config/initializers/inflections.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'drive', 'drives'
  inflect.singular 'drives', 'drive'
end
```

Now my routes are:

```
     business_pledge_drives GET    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives(.:format)                                         pledge_drives#index
                            POST   /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives(.:format)                                         pledge_drives#create
  new_business_pledge_drive GET    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/new(.:format)                                     pledge_drives#new
 edit_business_pledge_drive GET    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/:id/edit(.:format)                                pledge_drives#edit
      business_pledge_drive GET    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/:id(.:format)                                     pledge_drives#show
                            PUT    /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/:id(.:format)                                     pledge_drives#update
                            DELETE /businesses/:business_id/pledge_drives/:id(.:format)                                     pledge_drives#destroy
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028992/custom-inflections-not-working-on-rails3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, rails knows about the correct pluralizations of the words, e.g: model name. 
However, In other cases, You can define correct conversions in rails using Inflections.